# Loading textures in THREE.js and Angular

Tags: angular, three.js

I'm trying to reproduce the [three.js cube example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cub#webgl_geometry_cube) in an Angular application,  but I get a cube with black faces. No errors in console.

When using normal mesh material (`var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();`) things works fine.

Angular: 7.0.4, three.js: 0.99

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cube',
  templateUrl: './cube.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cube.component.scss']
})
export class CubeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var mesh;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 400;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('assets/model/crate.gif');

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
    // var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);  

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Texture loading is async. You render only once, before the textures are loaded, so they show up black.

If you do not want to render continuously, Three.JS offers a [LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager) with an onLoad event that fires when the textures are fully loaded: you could render inside that event. You can also [wrap the loading behavior inside a promise](https://itnext.io/promise-loading-with-three-js-78a6297652a5), it that is your style.